# Shortening lines in a .txt file using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, text-manipulation

I have a .txt file that has 98 lines.  I need to shorten each of these lines so that I only have the first 14 characters in each line.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Which OS: Windows, Linux, OS X, ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colrm 15 < foo.txt
```

Looks good and might do what you want.

You will need to direct the output to another file, if you want to save the results.

Comment: This is a command to remove columns.  I only have one column, and I need to shorten the length of each line within this column to 14 characters.  Each line is relatively long, but can be identified by the first 14 characters.

Each line looks like this:

TCGA-04-1514-01A-01D-0500-02_S01_CGH_105_Dec08.txt

And I want this:

TCGA-04-1514-0

Comment: @T.J.: Um, please try my command first.  The columns it is removing are character columns, not space separated columns.

Comment: $ colrm 15 matched-tumor-before-gc.ov.txt 
colrm: illegal column -- matched-tumor-before-gc.ov.txt

Comment: do `colrm 15 <  matched-tumor-before-gc.ov.txt`

Answer (score 1):

If Linux:

```
cut -c -14 myfile.txt > mycutfile.txt
```

What this does is take the first 14 characters (`-14` is a shortcut for `1-14`) of each line of the original file and pipe them out to the new file.